# Laravel validate the field on the basis of value of another field

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I want to validate two fields i.e. 'type' and 'options' where 'type' field is enum. The 'options' field should be validated only if the value of 'type' field is 'opt'.

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'type' => 'required|in:opt,number,text,file,image',
    'options'=>the condition I need(if type is 'opt')
]);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use required_if validation in Laravel.

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'type' => 'required|in:opt,number,text,file,image',
    'options'=> 'required_if:type,==,opt'
]);
```

Here is a Documentation [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-required-if)

Comment: This seems to be better solution. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You can add validation conditionally like this

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'type' => 'required|in:opt,number,text,file,image',
        'options'=>($input['type'] == 'opt')?'required':''
    ]);
```

Comment: This is not a standard way of doing it. You should follow the documentation when they are providing you a way. Please check my answer below maybe it can help you. @tayyab_fareed

Comment: Yes I checked and Accepted that as the answer. Thanks